# elasticsearch n-gram tokenizer with match_phrase not giving expected result

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a index as follow

```
PUT /ngram_tokenizer
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "test_name": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
    }
  } 
},
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 20
    },
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars":[
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "whitespace",
            "symbol"
            ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then indexed as follow

```
POST /ngram_tokenizer/_doc
{
  "test_name": "test document"
}
```

```
POST /ngram_tokenizer/_doc
{
  "test_name": "another document"
}
```

Then I did a match_phrase query,

```
GET /ngram_tokenizer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "test_name": "document"
      
  }
}
}
```

Above query returns both document as expected, but below query didn't return any document

```
GET /ngram_tokenizer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "test_name": "test"
      
  }
}
}
```

also, I checked all the tokens it generates by following query

```
POST ngram_tokenizer/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "test document"
}
```

match query works fine, can you guys help me

**Update**

when I want to search for a phrase I have to do a match_phrase query right? Then I used n-gram tokenizer on that field because, if there is any typo in the search term, still i can get a similar doc. Also, I know that we can use fuzziness to overcome typo issues in search terms. But when I used fuzziness in match queries or fuzzy queries there was a scoring issue as mentioned here. Actually what I want is, when I do a match query I want to get results even though there is a typo in search terms. And in the match_phrase query, I should get proper results at least when I search without any typos.

Answer (score 1):

It's because at search time, the analyzer used to analyze the input text is the same as the one used at indexing time, i.e. `my_analyzer`, and the `match_phrase` query is a bit more complex than the `match` query.

At search time, you should simply use the `standard` analyzer (or something different than the ngram analyzer) in order to analyze your query input.

The following query shows how to make it work as you expect.

```
GET /ngram_tokenizer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "test_name": {
        "query": "test",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also specify the `standard` analyzer as a `search_analyzer` in your mapping

```
"test_name": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "search_analyzer": "standard"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did the changes as you said, But it gave result when I did match_phrase query for `test`. But  match_phrase query for 'test document' didn't give any result. Before it was giving result

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of running a match_phrase query on tokens analyzed by an ngram analyzer, can you explain your use case in more details?

Comment: I have updated my use case. Please go through it.

Comment: Thanks but you need to update your question, not my answer ;-)

Comment: Sorry. It was by mistake

Comment: No prob, let me know when your question is updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248399/discussion-between-sudheesh-and-val).

Comment: question is updated. Please check.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're mixing a few concepts here, ngram, fuzziness, match_phrase can be combined but carefully, which is not the case here